# Can you fix it or tell me what's wrong with this? I want to get Navigacio upper

Tags: html, css

I got a problem with my code:
So I wrote a simple html and css code Like a simple web page. Then the "Navigacio" is bugging or I dont know it's more in the bottom, but I want it to get this to the top next to "En egy 13 eves srac vagyok..." . So can you help me out?
Here's a picture (the bug is in my secondary display):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejlp5.png

The code:

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, san-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  background-color: white;
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#header {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#content {
  padding: 10px;
}

#nav {
  width: 180px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 500px;
}

#nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0
}

#main {
  width: 600;
  float: right;
  color: black;
}

#footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #999999;
  color: white;
  text-align: right
}

#nav .kivalasztott {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stilusv2.css" />
</head>


<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Rolam</h1>

    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="main">
        <p> En egy 13 eves srac vagyok, most tanulok programozni HTML-t es CSS-t.
          <p>
            <p>Jelenleg csak nokedli szaggato szintu vagyok az egeszben, van alapveto batch programozasi tudasom, de nem eleg mindenhez, ismereteimet folyamatosan bovitem...</p>
            <p> Az egyik celom egy sajat jatekot, vagy programot fejleszteni gepre/telefonra.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="nav">
        <h3>Navigacio</h3>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="Kezdolap" href="file:///D:/Don%C3%A1t/Programoz%C3%A1s/html/Css.html">Kezdolap</li>
      <li><a class="kivalasztott" href="file:///D:/Don%C3%A1t/Programoz%C3%A1s/html/rolam.html">Rolam</li>
      <li>Elerhetoseg</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
      Copyright &copy; 2019 Szigeti Donat 
      
      </div>
      
     </div>
    </div>
     </body>

    </html>
```

I think I made a mistake in the CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the #nav div before the #main div like so :

```
    <div id="content">
    <div id="nav">
    <h3>Navigacio</h3>
    <ul>
    <li><a class="Kezdolap" href="file:///D:/Don%C3%A1t/Programoz%C3%A1s/html/Css.html">Kezdolap</li>
    <li><a class="kivalasztott" href="file:///D:/Don%C3%A1t/Programoz%C3%A1s/html/rolam.html">Rolam</li>
    <li>Elerhetoseg</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
    <p> En egy 13 eves srac vagyok, most tanulok programozni HTML-t es CSS-t.<p>
    <p>Jelenleg csak nokedli szaggato szintu vagyok az egeszben, van alapveto batch programozasi tudasom, de nem eleg mindenhez, ismereteimet folyamatosan bovitem...</p>
    <p> Az egyik celom egy sajat jatekot, vagy programot fejleszteni gepre/telefonra.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
```